# How to get the AMS mathbb font while using Palatino elsewhere

Tags: fonts, amsmath, mathpazo, blackboard

I'm a Latex user. I've been using Palatino for typesetting a piece mathematical text:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
```

The results are good, however I don't like the blackboard-bold given by mathpazo. Is there some option to pass to mathpazo, or some nice hack that will give me back my beloved AMSmath `\mathbb` symbols?

Comment: - we've heard so many criticisms of the `\mathbb` alphabet here at ams that it's nice to hear it called "beloved".  thanks!

Comment: Let me add in my affection for the ams \mathbb symbols as well :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to restate the meaning of `\mathbb`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}}
```

This should go somewhere after loading **mathpazo**.

Comment: How about the font for \varmathbb?

Answer (score 5):

give the `kpfonts` a try, they are similiar to palatino, but have also sans serif and typewriter fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\mathbb{F}\mathbb{D}\mathbb{G}\mathbb{H}$

\normalsize
Serif text, and
\textsf{Sans Serif}, and 
\texttt{Typewriter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is in fact a package option for this: if you pass `noBBpl` to `mathpazo`, then its blackboard bold fonts are not loaded. That also means you have to load the AMS ones separately, but that just means using `amssymb`, which is simpler than defining another symbol font alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
% these two \usepackage commands make it work
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[noBBpl]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\begin{document}
In this document,
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathbb N$ will denote the natural numbers,
    \item $\mathbb Z$ will denote the integers,
    \item $\mathbb Q$ will denote the rational numbers,
    \item $\mathbb R$ will denote the real numbers, and
    \item $\mathbb C$ will denote the complex numbers.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]